# unable to install-grub/dev/sda in windows 10 ubuntu 16.04.2 dual boot

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.2 alongside Windows 10 creator update, but every time I run the installer I get a `grub` error saying

> failed install-grub/dev/sda- this is a fatal error

I tried the **Install alongside Windows** option and the manual "something else" option but both give the same error.

I tried running the boot-repair but it failed to fix the issue and generated [this script](https://pastebin.com/raw/GXZJ5yzt).

**Laptop Details**:

- Dell Inspiron 5559
- i7 processor -6th gen
- 16 GB ram
- 2 TB HDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found on some systems, that the error isn't actually the install but grub update that fails. the file /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware errors breaking the  creation of grubs config file.

edit it to read:

> set -e
>
> gettext_printf "Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration\n" >&2
>
> cat << EOF
>
> menuentry 'uefi-firmware' {
>
> fwsetup
>
> }
>
> EOF

and the grub install should complete.

Comment: I'm not getting the file specified by you. Should I insert usb, click try ubuntu and search in ubuntu or in the files of bootable usb?

Comment: it is in the files of the install. It is easiest if you can edit it during the install. the last line of the installer menu should be a command prompt. nano is the file editor, and `exit` leaves the command shell. if not finish the install with out a boot loader then use the live CD to fix it